# Issue for Azure service bus with Stencil js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nextTick') at Connection._register

Tags: typescript, azure, azureservicebus, stenciljs, tsx

I have this issue when i'm using **Azure Service Bus** with **Stencil js** library to use a sender.
I configured azure service bus as explained in the official guide in Microsoft website: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues .

I don't receive messages in portal.azure.com.

- I installed v **^7.7.0 of @azure/service-bus**.
- My **node version is^16.14.0**
- **Npm version is 8.3.1**
- **Webpack version is ^5.72.0**
- **dotenv: "^16.0.1"**
- **rollup-plugin-node-polyfills: "^0.2.1"**

But when i start the server on stencil, i find in console the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nextTick') at Connection._register.
```

Here the complete error in console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoJZe.png

Code used is simple and is the following in the componentWillRender function:

```
async componentWillRender() {
const serviceBusClient = new asb.ServiceBusClient(this.connectionString);

let sender = serviceBusClient.createSender(this.queueName);

await sender.sendMessages({body:"prova prova"})


 render() {
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```

In stencil.conf.js i have the following parameters:

```
export const config: Config = { namespace:'provaprovaprova', .... ...., plugins: [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ process: "process/browser", }), new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"], }), ], nodeResolve:{ extensions: [".ts", ".js", "tsx"], module:true, }, rollupPlugins: { after: [ nodePolyfills(), ]}, }
```

I tried also to use batch solution to send an array as messages in queue, but i have the same error seen before.

**(in javascript version with only js files send.js and receiver.js i can do everything correctly using node to execute send.js and receiver.js as in the example of official guide).**

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You are getting the typeerror because somewhere some function or a variable is not initialized in your code.

Comment: no it wasn't that... I open an issue on github and microsoft help me, it was a problem with polyfill.

Comment: For reference here's the github issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/23051#issuecomment-1234647438